# Parenthesized pattern within a cons pattern

Tags: .net, f#, pattern-matching

From the Microsoft guide of [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching), there is an example of Parenthesized Pattern:

> Parentheses can be grouped around patterns to achieve the desired associativity. In the following example, parentheses are used to control associativity between an AND pattern and a cons pattern.

```
let countValues list value =
    let rec checkList list acc =
       match list with
       | (elem1 & head) :: tail when elem1 = value -> checkList tail (acc + 1)
       | head :: tail -> checkList tail acc
       | [] -> acc
    checkList list 0

countValues [ for x in -10..10 -> x*x - 4 ] 0
```

How does the `(elem1 & head) :: tail when elem1 = value` pattern work? Is this the same as:

```
| head :: tail when elem1 = value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have to admit that I fail to see the usefulness of this particular example.

The grouping in your case just means that it matches the same value to two different variables, `head` and `elem1` both contain the head of the list.

A more simplified example of this match would be

```
let (a & b) = x
x = a // true
x = b // true
a = b // true

let (head & elem1) :: tail = [1;2;3;4]
head = 1 // true
elem1 = 1 // true
tail = [2;3;4] // true
```

So given your example, the pattern simply equals to

```
| head :: tail when head = value
```

Side note, you can place parenthesis over any and all pattern.

Comment: Typo: `::` instead of `&`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Thanks for spotting that :)

Answer (score 4):

The example from the documentation is a pretty bad choice to illustrate that particular paragraph - it uses the esoteric and notoriously useless `&` pattern that seems to draw the entire attention to itself, and detract from the point of the paragraph.

The point being made is that there's a difference between this:

```
...
match list with
| elem1 & head :: tl -> ...
...
```

and this:

```
...
match list with
| (elem1 & head) :: tl -> ...
...
```

where in the first example `elem1` is bound to the entire list, while in the second example it's bound only to the first element of the list (as its name would suggest), due to parens enforcing order of operations.

A much simpler illustration would be just showing how a `a::b::tl` and `(a::b)::tl` reflect different types (respectively an `'a list` and an `'a list list`).